# How do I edit the current empty line in an editor, without having it filled with previous command?

Tags: bash

Apparently since the release of bash v. 5 some weeks ago (witnessed on Arch Linux and Debian Buster), the default behaviour of invoking the editor in vi mode has changed.

```
set -o vi
<Esc>v
```

**bash 4.x and earlier:** an empty `$EDITOR` pops up.

**bash 5.x:** `$EDITOR` opens with the last executed command (resembling the `fc` command).

Accidental opening of the command-line editor and violently `:q!`ing it leads to the repeated execution of the last command.
For a long-time vi-mode addict, this is unexpected behaviour and violates the principle of least astonishment.
How to revert to the old empty-editor state?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this has turned out to be [a real bug in bash](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-02/msg00039.html), that has already found its way into major distribution releases like, amongst others, Debian Buster and FreeBSD 11.3 and 12.0.

At least for Arch Linux, there is [bash-devel-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/bash-devel-git/) that is not affected.

Comment: some links to the bug-bash discussions and/or git commits will not hurt.

Comment: Just spent the last few minutes trying to see what I messed up in my bash config that caused this annoying `:q!` behavior, and took me a while to find this.  Surprised to find this is an actual bug in bash